# Android O Notification led setLights() deprecated, setLightColor() with blink?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I have this code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("test", getString(R.string.notification_channel_news), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.YELLOW);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(pattern);
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("desc");

        Log.e("notif", channel.shouldShowLights() + "");

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "test")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setLights(Color.YELLOW,5,5)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification not = notificationBuilder.build();
```

How can I set the delay of led like depracated `.setLights(Color.YELLOW,5,5)`? Because on android O, `.setLights(Color.YELLOW,5,5)` is not working at all.

Comment: I have the same question, did you get an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot - it seems the Android API no longer allows customizing the blink pattern.